# How to plot a function that contain logarithm

Tags: arrays, numpy, matplotlib, plot, logarithm

I am a beginner, I try to plot the absolute square of a function that contain logarithm first I had an error saying:
Only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars.

Then I tried to fix it by the following code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import I
import math

f=lambda r:np.abs((-31415.9 *I) *math.log(r)/ math.log(10) - (49348 + 292886*I) - 1.97392e8 *r + (3.10063e11 *I) *r**2 + 4.3293e14*r**3 - (5.10034e17*I)*r**4 - 5.12743e20*r**5)**2
r=np.arange(1, 5, 2.7)
y = np.vectorize(f)
plt.plot(r, y(r))
```

But the plot I get is just a straight line, which seems absurd to me. Please help me I am really confused.[The straight line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QTsx.png)

I want to obtain the Airy pattern in Fresnel diffraction. So I just try to plot the absolute square result of the Huygens integral and I expected to obtain something wider than the Fraunhofer diffraction with bessel function.

Comment: What is the output of `print(r)`?

Comment: The result of `print(r)`  is [1.  3.7]

Comment: So you are creating a plot connecting two points. That's a straight line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes it is true but I can not define r as `np.linspace` as I take the error: `ValueError: math domain error`. So what can I do to have a proper plot?

Comment: Choose more than 2 values for `r` but not those that cause a math domain error.

Comment: You don't get the error *because* you use `linspace`, but because of the values you passed to it. Make sure you only create a range of values for which your `f` function is defined mathematically.

Comment: `r = np.linspace(1, 5, 200)` should work fine.

Comment: You don't need sympy for complex numbers. Complex numbers are built-in in python. Add `j` after a bunch of digits to make a pure imaginary number: for instance you can write `49348 + 292886j`. This will work better with numpy than using sympy's complex numbers. In general, avoid mixing numpy and sympy.

Comment: Also module `math` has a `log10` function, so you can write `math.log10(r)` directly rather than `math.log(r) / math.log(10)`.